# No for loops in elixir. How can I make a board?

Tags: for-loop, recursion, io, elixir

Here is a snippet of the for loop so far. The problem is decrementing spaces variable

```
for i <- 0..(row-1) do
  for j <- 0..(col-1) do

  if j == 0 do
  IO.write"+"
  end 

 IO.write "--+"
end
IO.puts ""
columns= col+1


for columns <- 1..columns do
if columns == 1 do
IO.write "|"
end

if spaces < 10 do
IO.write " "
IO.write spaces
IO.write "|"

end

end
spaces = spaces - 1 <- This won't decrement after it goes through the forloop again!
end

end
```

I need to make a board game in Elixir that outputs something like this.

```
+---+---+---+
| 12| 11| 10|
|B  |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|  7|  8|  9|
| a |  S| e |
+---+---+---+
|  6|  5|  4|
| e |  L|Ad |
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

I've done it on java with the following code using a for loop within another for loop essentially, but this is not possible on elixir. Is there any idea on how to approach this? Thanks.

EDIT: in case anyone wants to see my java code, here it is.

```
public class math {
static int col = 10;
static int row = 10;
static String top= "---+";
static String side= "|";
static int spaces=col*row;
static int columns; 
static int dash;
static String player="A";
public static void main(String args[]){

    for ( int i=0; i < row; i++ ){
        for ( int j=0; j < col; j++ ){
            if ( j==0) System.out.print("+");

            System.out.print(top);


        }

        System.out.print("\n");
        columns=col+1;

        while( columns > 1){
        if(columns == col+1){
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        if( spaces < 10){
        System.out.print("  "+spaces+"|");}
        else if (spaces <100){
            System.out.print(" "+spaces+"|");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(""+spaces+"|");
        }
        spaces--;
        columns--;}


        System.out.print("\n");
        columns=col+1;
        while(columns >1){
            if (columns == col +1) {System.out.print("|");}
        System.out.print("   |");
        columns--;}
        System.out.print("\n");
        if( i == row-1){
            int botside = col;
            while(botside !=0){
                if(botside == col){
                    System.out.print("+");
                }
            System.out.print(top);
            botside--;}
            }
            }

            }
```

Comment: Your question as it is right now is mostly about translating the string manipulation you're doing in Java to Elixir. If you can simplify to get to the core of the problem (like you're trying to visit the fields of the board in a certain order and maintain some state throughout), you'll probably get some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [for special form](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) for list comprehension to achieve what you need with something like:

```
for i <- 0..(row-1) do
  for j <- 0..(col-1) do
     # Rest of the code
  end
end
```

Comment: While this works, I just want to point out that it is not a for loop and behaves very differently. This is called a comprehension. Also, you do not need to nest the comprehensions. You can do something like this `for i <- 0..(row-1), j <- 0..(col-1) do ... end`

Comment: Ya im having problems with numbering each box. I denoted a variable called spaces = row * col so a 2x2 board would have spaces = 4, and then in  the each comprehension i tell it to print out spaces and at the end i tell spaces to decrement by 1. However, spaces does not update when I do this :S It says 3 for each box.

Comment: @bossrevs please update the original question with your code attempt in Elixir.

Comment: Thanks @JustinWood, my wording in the answer was misleading, updated to remove references to for as a loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution - based on a board template that you fill with your data.

```
defmodule Main do

def main(  ) do

 data = 
 [
   "B  ", "   ",  "   ",
   " a ", "  S",  " e ",
   " e ", "  L",  "Ad ",
   "   ", "   ",  "   ", 
   "" #required terminal
 ]

IO.puts print_board( data )

end

defp print_board( data ) do

board = """
+---+---+---+
| 12| 11| 10|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|  7|  8|  9|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|  6|  5|  4|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
"""

String.split( board,"   ")  # Splits board string into a list of strings
 |>  Enum.zip(  data )  # interleaves with data - as list of tuples
 |> Enum.map( fn {a,b} -> a <> b end )  # maps tuples back to merge the list.
end

end
```

My testing shows it produces your required result when you run `Main.main`

Comment: The problem is that the board can vary depending on what you put the rows and columns as. In this case its a 4 x 3 but you can input any size board. Same with the placements of the ladders such as S and e from your data list.

Comment: @boss_revs the input = row, cols and data.  Can we assume that the data is passed as a string like the one I wrote? If not how is it formatted?